# Web Service and Log4J Output to File

Tags: java, service, log4j, apache-axis

So, I have the log4j configurations set up and it output to the console just fine. But I need it to output to a file now. I am using Axis2 in Eclipse Galileo.
I edited the default log4j.properties file to this:

```
Set root category priority to INFO and its only appender to CONSOLE.
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE, LOGFILE

 Set the enterprise logger priority to FATAL
log4j.logger.org.apache.axis2.enterprise=FATAL
log4j.logger.de.hunsicker.jalopy.io=FATAL
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header=FATAL
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=FATAL

 CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %m%n

 LOGFILE is set to be a File appender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=C:\Users\*username*\Desktop\Android\Android_WS\src\wtp\AndroidWS_Log.log
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

But the output is still not getting to the Log file. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove line 2:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE
```

Also, try using a forward slash, '/' for the directory separator:

```
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=C:/Users/*username*/Desktop/Android/Android_WS/src/wtp/AndroidWS_Log.log
```

Comment: I will try the forward slash, but line 2 is commented out.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your server has write access rights to the log file.

Comment: How exactly do I do that? I am new to log4J and fairly new to Web Services in general.

Comment: This has to do with the OS you are using and the way it handles users. Your server runs with a user account that can't access files in your user directory.